# Are there Graph Polynomials?

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, polynomials

Knots can be represented by polynomials like the [Jones polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jones_polynomial). Is there a comparable representation for graphs? How does it work for subclasses like planar, k-regular...?

Google doesn't really help [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=graph+polynomial&hl=de&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=k3e&tbo=u&rls=org.mozilla%3ade%3aofficial&tbm=isch&source=univ&sa=X&ei=vOW7UKvNJMqE4gTt_YDIDw&ved=0CDYQsAQ&biw=1787&bih=738)...

Thanks

Comment: Googling "graph polynomial" will of course give a bunch of links about how to graph polynomials. Googling "graph theory polynomial" is much more successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also check out the [Tutte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_polynomial) polynomial.  It is actually a generalization of many polynomials in graph theory, including the chromatic polynomial and the Jones polynomial.  It's not a "representation" of the graph, per se, but is extensively used.

Comment: How could I have missed this page. It was on [page 4](https://www.google.com/search?q=graph+polynomial&hl=de&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=ZPK&tbo=d&rls=org.mozilla:de:official&source=lnms&sa=X&ei=Aua7UL7XBMT44QTFkIDABg&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAA&biw=1787&bih=738#q=graph+polynomial&hl=de&safe=off&client=firefox-a&tbo=d&rls=org.mozilla:de:official&ei=8-q7UKHJFMnEsgbzhIG4AQ&start=30&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=ca003bcddda1de26&bpcl=39314241&biw=1787&bih=738)... at least the first link to something related.

Answer (score 5):

There are polynomial invariants for graphs. One of them is the characteristic polynomial of the adjacency matrix. This has been studied extensively, for example in connection with the *graph isomorphism problem*.